# How to get the resources (Images/JSP/CSS) and their properties which got involved in Servlet Response

Tags: servlets, httpresponse, servlet-filters

Once I got the servlet response,I need to check what are the resources involved in it.

Like the below

> 1) What is JSP/HTML's relative path,name which is coming as a servlet response
>
> 2) What is the Images/CSS/Scripts involved in the response view files (JSP/HTML)

Can filter be useful at this point or any other approach, if it is then how? Any guidelines will be great help.

Comment: It is not clear what you need, where do you need it, in what format and what will this be used for

Comment: My primary requirement is at run time I need to get whats the relative path of the JSP which got rendered in the browser.So that I can uniquely identify the JSP, which is going to be reviewed

Comment: if you execute `http://localhost:8080/demo1/jsps/newjsp.jsp`, what exactly do you want to get? (where `demo1` is the application name )

Comment: yes demo1 will be context root. The application will not be developed by me.To be precise once application is deployed user will navigate through pages and mark some of the sensitive fields on that.That marked field will belongs to some JSP right, so there I need that JSP's properties like path and name and some more

Comment: what properties would you need?

Comment: One more thing, we will be marking this kind of sensitive fields for many applications. So I need to have some program through which I need to identify the pages.

Comment: I need to get the path of the JSP. For example assume AccountNumber be the sensitive field,but this may exist in many pages.So I need to know which AccountNumber one Which page is sensitive